# Build Alarm Clock app for Mac

Tags: c++, macos

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the correct direction for writing a Alarm Clock app for OS X. I've looked for tutorials but cannot seem to find anything even remotely similar for OS X. I have applications now but they just don't seem to look right or work right so I thought I'd make one seeing as I've been meaning to learn C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't vouch for the code quality, but a bit of searching and I found this project on Github https://github.com/dev2dev/Alarm-Clock

Note: Mac programming is done in Obj-C and while you can write C it generally isn't needed. Here are a couple of links talking about obj-c and c++

- http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects
- http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.03/CandObjectiveCCompared/index.html

There is a lot more out there on the subject; but should give you some where to start from.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use bash instead of C++, here is a script, which you use as

`wake 100 Wake now &`

and will display the message after the given number of seconds.

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep $1
shift

osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    beep
    display alert "$*"
end tell

return
EOF
```

Comment: The question is specifically tagged C++